# Recorrer un objecto json con multiples niveles de array con Gson

Tags: java, android, android-studio, json, gson

estoy teniendo problemas para poder recorrer correctamente un `json` usando la **librería Gson**, contiene múltiples niveles de Array y no se como recorrerlo correctamente el arreglo `json`.

**jSon - Múltiples Niveles**

```
{ 
  "date_layout":"day-month-year",
  "lastupdate":1547596830,
    "items":[{
      "name":"Cleans Cuts",
      "featured":"true",
      "item":{
        "image":"http:www.dominio.com/imagen_no_deseada.jpg",
           "images":{
              "transparent":"http:www.dominio.com/imagen_deseada1.jpg",
              "transparent_blank":"http:www.dominio.com/imagen_deseada2.jpg",
              "transparent_dark":"http:www.dominio.com/imagen_deseada3.jpg"
             }
          }
    }]
}
```

Lo que me gustaría obtener son las **IMAGES[transparent]**, ¿qué pasos debo seguir para obtener los parámetros deseados?

Lo que tengo realizado es lo siguiente, 2 clases modelos para obtener los datos `json`.

**Datos.java**

```
public class Datos {
    public String date_layout;
    public Int lastupdate;
    List<items> items;
}
```

**items.java**

```
public class items {
    public String name;
    //public ArrayList<item> item;
}
```

El comentario **`//public ArrayList<item> item;`**, creía que se debía hacer otra lista anidada, pero resulta que no funciona así. Por ese motivo esta comentada.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String url = "http://www.midominio.com/archivo.json";

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
               .url(url)
               .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        if(response.isSuccessful()) {
            String response_jSon = response.body().string();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Datos datosFinal = gson.fromJson(response_jSon, Datos.class);

            for (int i=0; i<datosFinal.items.size(); i++) {
                Log.d("MENSAJE_2", datosFinal.items.get(i).name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Por el momento en el Log solo muestra el `Cleans Cuts` pero todavía queda recorrer Arrays hasta llegar a **IMAGES[transparent]**

Comment: El primer requisito es **partir de un JSON válido**. El JSON que presentas no lo es, por tanto, nada se puede hacer mientras el JSON no sea válido. Presenta primero un JSON válido y entonces podremos ayudarte. Puedes usar alguna herramienta en línea para validar el JSON y saber los errores que tiene, [por ejemplo esta](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com). Tu objeto debe pasar esa validación previa sí o sí.

Comment: Como comenta A.Cedano, nada se puede realizar ya que el jSon que presentas no tiene estructura de un JSon, revisalo aquí https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Tienes toda la razón A.Cedano, lo acabo de corregir @Elenasys. Ha hora pasa el check. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ya he conseguido la solucion, no debo de crear ArrayList si no que se debe seguir definiendo los array dentro de los modelos. Os dejo unos ejemplos:

```
public class items {
    public String name;
    public String featured;
    public Item item;
}
```

Crear otra clase modelo **item**

```
public class Item{
    public String image;
    public Image images;
}
```

Crear otra clase modelo **imagen**

```
public class Image {
    public String transparent;
    public String transparent_blank;
    public String transparent_dark;
}
```

Y luego el **Bucle**.

```
Datos datosFinal = gson.fromJson(response_jSon, Datos.class);
 for (int i=0; i<datosFinal.items.size(); i++){
        Log.d("msg_2", datosFinal.items.get(i).item.images.transparent);
        Log.d("msg_2", datosFinal.items.get(i).item.images.transparent_blank);
        Log.d("msg_2", datosFinal.items.get(i).item.images.transparent_dark);
}
```